# Sort Order Items Alphabetically With Some Exceptions

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I use a snippet to sort my Woocommerce order items alphabetically, but there are several clerical line items (PO#, Terms, Discount) that I need to always be displayed first or last.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', function( $items, $order ) {

 uasort( $items, 
 function( $a, $b ) { 
 return strnatcmp( $a['name'], $b['name'] ); 
 }
 );

 return $items;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Is there a way to modify this code to allow certain items to always be displayed first or last?

Comment: Confused as to why PO#, Terms, and Discount show up as line items on the order. Is that really the way Woo does it?

Comment: We use Woocommerce as a preorder system. All the invoicing is done in Quickbooks, which is synced to our multiple woo sites. Having line items for fees and discounts is the best way we’ve found to keep the accounting organized in QBO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked the sorting function to handle these specific items

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', function( $items, $order ) {
    
    $prioritizedItems = ['PO#', 'Terms', 'Discount']; // Items which needs to be displayed first

    uasort($items, function($a, $b) use ($prioritizedItems) {
        // Check if either item is in the prioritized list
        $a_priority = in_array($a['name'], $prioritizedItems);
        $b_priority = in_array($b['name'], $prioritizedItems);

        // If both or neither of them are prioritized, then you can sort alphabetically
        if ($a_priority === $b_priority) {
            return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
        }

        // If a single one is prioritized, it should come first
        return $a_priority ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return $items;

}, 10, 2 );
```